# Does $T= qV$ hold true for relativistic case?

Tags: special-relativity, electrostatics

In relativistic case, kinetic energy $T\ne 1/2mv^2$, m is mass and v is speed. But if a particle( initially at rest) of charge q is accelerated through a potential difference $V$ the kinetic energy will be equal to the work done, in other words, $T=qV.$ I read $T= qV$ holds true for relativistic case. Is it true?  Why is that happen ?

Comment: How are you defining $V$?

Comment: jacob1729, V is the potential difference. So the charged particle moves from higher potential to lower potential. Since it was originally at rest, it gains some amount of kinetic energy due to the potential difference V.

Answer (score 1):

The equations of electromagnetism (Maxwell equations) are completely Lorentz-invariant. In General, the quantity

$q_\mu A^\mu = q_0 A^0 + q_1 A^1 + q_2 A^2 + q_3 A^3$

with 4-charge $q_\mu$ (here $q_0$ is charge and $(q_1,q_2,q_3)$ the Electric current vector) and 4-potential $A^\mu$ (here $A_0=V$ and $(A_1,A_2,A_3)$ is Vector potential such that the magnetic field $\vec{B}$ can be expressed as $rot (A_1,A_2,A_3) = (B_1,B_2,B_3)$)

is invariant under Lorentz transformations.

So in Absence of magnetic fields or Electric currents, we have a Lorentz-invariant quantity $q_0A^0$ and the Statement $T = qV$ is correct.